# Expand command in an argument before the main command

Tags: expansion, xsim

Related to my problem for `xsim` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495478/exercises-imported-dont-print-when-i-call-a-collection).

I want to use commands `\ExOption` and `\ExPart` to implement more easily my collection in `xsim` package. But i'm facing the problem that my commands do not expand in `\DeclareExerciseCollection{\ExOption_\ExPart}`. In the `aux` file i can find this line : `\XSIM {collection:\ExOption _\ExPart }{}` who point to me that there is no expansion.

How can i make my commands expanded before the macros `\DeclareExerciseCollection{}` and avoid spaces implement by TeX after a macro ? I've read some information about `\expandafter` and `\edef` and i think it can be helpfull but it's the first time i've to deal with those commands.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}


%%Declaration exercices
    \edef\ExOption{default}
    \edef\ExPart{default}

%%Declaration Collection
    \renewcommand{\ExOption}{5M4}
    \renewcommand{\ExPart}{AlgebreFinanciere}

    \DeclareExerciseCollection{\ExOption_\ExPart}       %%With custom commands produce wrong output
%   \DeclareExerciseCollection{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}   %%With applicable name produce good output
\begin{document}
\chapter{Where i want exercises}
%%Collecting exercises
    \collectexercises{\ExOption_\ExPart}                %%With custom commands produce wrong output
        \begin{exercise}
            Can you print me ?
        \end{exercise}
        \begin{solution}
            Yes, you can !
        \end{solution}
    \collectexercisesstop{\ExOption_\ExPart}

%   \collectexercises{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}            %%With applicable name produce good output
%       \begin{exercise}
%           Can you print me ?
%       \end{exercise}
%       \begin{solution}
%           Yes, you can !
%       \end{solution}
%   \collectexercisesstop{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}

%%Print
Output of the command in LaTeX \verb|\ExOption_\ExPart| : \ExOption\_\ExPart


    \printcollection{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a current version of pdftex (that defines `\expanded`) you can define expanding versions of the commands as shown below.

With older implementations without `\expanded` you can use `\edef`:

```
\newcommand\xDeclareExerciseCollection[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{\noexpand\DeclareExerciseCollection{#1}}\tmp}
```

and similarly for the other two commands.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}

\newcommand\xDeclareExerciseCollection[1]{%
  \expandafter\DeclareExerciseCollection\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}
\newcommand\xcollectexercises[1]{%
  \expandafter\collectexercises\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}
\newcommand\xcollectexercisesstop[1]{%
  \expandafter\collectexercisesstop\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}

%%Declaration exercices
    \edef\ExOption{default}
    \edef\ExPart{default}

%%Declaration Collection
    \renewcommand{\ExOption}{5M4}
    \renewcommand{\ExPart}{AlgebreFinanciere}

    \xDeclareExerciseCollection{\ExOption_\ExPart}       %%With custom commands produce wrong output
%   \DeclareExerciseCollection{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}   %%With applicable name produce good output
\begin{document}
\chapter{Where i want exercises}
%%Collecting exercises
    \xcollectexercises{\ExOption_\ExPart}                %%With custom commands produce wrong output
        \begin{exercise}
            Can you print me ?
        \end{exercise}
        \begin{solution}
            Yes, you can !
        \end{solution}
    \xcollectexercisesstop{\ExOption_\ExPart}

%   \collectexercises{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}            %%With applicable name produce good output
%       \begin{exercise}
%           Can you print me ?
%       \end{exercise}
%       \begin{solution}
%           Yes, you can !
%       \end{solution}
%   \collectexercisesstop{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}

%%Print
Output of the command in LaTeX \verb|\ExOption_\ExPart| : \ExOption\_\ExPart


    \printcollection{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, the console says that the commands `\x...` are not defined. It does not produce an error for the definition but when they are called. Related to your remark about `\expanded` ? I'll update my version of pdftex and retry it.

Comment: @Piroooh I always run the code before posting, it does not give errors on a current system. The error (in the log) on older systems would not say `\x...` is undefined it will say `\expanded` is undefined. (if you use texlive you need texlive 2019) but I give the version without `\expanded` as well.

Comment: sorry, i didn't say it correctly. I wanted to say it doesn't work on my side and was curious to see the error that commands are not defined and not over `\expanded` for which you warned me. I continue to test if i can update version to test `\expanded` answer. The solution without `\expanded` seems to compile but it takes a while to (~5min and do not make an output). Is it normal ?

Comment: @Piroooh I ran it in a second or two, you must be looping somewhere. Did you change all three `\x..` commands?  But for the expanded version check your log for the actual error message (not any misleading summary from your editor) it should show `\expanded` as the undefined command.

Comment: Yes, i've changed the three definition commands. Seems i compile my documents with TeXLive 2017... I'll install the 2019 version first to tackle the problem !

Comment: @Piroooh  updating may be a good idea anyway but don't update the entire system just for this! I just used `\expanded` as I don't think I'd used it yet in an answer, and this was an opportunity. The `\edef` version is fine in this case (or the other answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94944/discussion-between-piroooh-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3):

I present two solutions here.

## First solution

This is in the same spirit as David Carlisle's solution, except that only one command needs to be defined for everything. You don't need a specific command for `\DeclareExerciseCollection`, for `\collectexercises`, for `\collectexercisesstop`, etc. Also, the command is implemented with LaTeX3—and thus not a fake of David Carlisle's solution. :-)

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pirooh_call_with_one_arg:Nn #1#2
  {
    #1 {#2}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pirooh_call_with_one_arg:Nn { Nx }

\NewDocumentCommand \callWithExpandedArg { m m }
  {
    % Perform full expansion on what #2 stands for, then call #1
    % with the result.
    \pirooh_call_with_one_arg:Nx #1 {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\ExOption}{5M4}
\newcommand*{\ExPart}{AlgebreFinanciere}

\callWithExpandedArg{\DeclareExerciseCollection}{\ExOption_\ExPart}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Where i want exercises}

\callWithExpandedArg{\collectexercises}{\ExOption_\ExPart}

\begin{exercise}
    Can you print me ?
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Yes, you can !
\end{solution}

\callWithExpandedArg{\collectexercisesstop}{\ExOption_\ExPart}

\callWithExpandedArg{\printcollection}{\ExOption_\ExPart}
\end{document}
```

## Second solution

Here, the approach is different. There is one command to define *per argument value,* not per `xsim` command such as `\DeclareExerciseCollection`, `\collectexercises`, `\collectexercisesstop` and `\printcollection` as in David Carlisle's solution. Here, the command `\callWithPredefinedArg` is defined for the argument value `5M4_AlgebreFinanciere` (you may want to adapt its name).

This solution isn't better than others, it's just different in spirit. The code does full expansion of `\ExOption` and `\ExPart` when `\callWithPredefinedArg` is defined (this could be changed if needed).

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}

\newcommand*{\ExOption}{default}
\newcommand*{\ExPart}{default}

\renewcommand*{\ExOption}{5M4}
\renewcommand*{\ExPart}{AlgebreFinanciere}

% This recursively expands \ExOption and \ExPart and “freezes”
% the result in the definition of \callWithPredefinedArg.
\edef\callWithPredefinedArg#1{#1{\ExOption_\ExPart}}

% Of course, you could achieve the same with:
%\def\callWithPredefinedArg#1{#1{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}}

\callWithPredefinedArg\DeclareExerciseCollection

\begin{document}
\chapter{Where i want exercises}

\callWithPredefinedArg\collectexercises

\begin{exercise}
    Can you print me ?
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Yes, you can !
\end{solution}

\callWithPredefinedArg\collectexercisesstop

\callWithPredefinedArg\printcollection

% If you have another chapter/module to start here, you could do
% \def\callWithPredefinedArg#1{#1{6N5_GeometrieFinanciere}}
% \callWithPredefinedArg\collectexercises
% etc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If i understand, `\callWithPredefinedArg` act as a "meta" command who allows me to expand the set up argument (here : `\ExOption_\ExPart`). So if i want to add another subdivisions (`\ExOption_\ExPart_\ExSubpart`), i have to redefine `\callWithPredefinedArg`. I think for my purpose it is simpler to work with DavidCarlisle answer. But it's nice to see alternative answer. Thank you !

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The argument value to pass to `xsim` commands (or whatever you use after `\callWithPredefinedArg`) is frozen at the time `\callWithPredefinedArg` is defined (I added comments that should clarify this, I hope).

Comment: I added another solution (“First solution”) in the spirit of David Carlisle's one, but “meta”-style as you put it, and based on LaTeX3.

Comment: Nice improve to add the second option. At the moment, the two solutions allows me to attempt what i was looking for and it solves my problem. For the consistency of syntax (near what `xsim` package defines) and because if i had to build other add-on, the David Carlisle's solution is more familiar to me (i'm unable right now to read `expl3` syntax), i'll use David Carlisle's solution. Unfortunately i can't accept the two solutions as an answer but thank you for your help !

Comment: It's actually a simple enough example to start understanding `expl3` code, but well...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility by defining variants of the corresponding internal macros - the `x` variants expand their arguments first before applying the actual macro to it (in the end this is the same as David's solution):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xsim_new_collection:n   {x}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xsim_start_collection:n {x}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xsim_stop_collection:n  {x}

\NewDocumentCommand \xDeclareExerciseCollection {m}
  { \xsim_new_collection:x {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand \xcollectexercises {m}
  { \xsim_start_collection:x {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand \xcollectexercisesstop {m}
  { \xsim_stop_collection:x {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\ExOption}{default}
\newcommand*{\ExPart}{default}

\renewcommand*{\ExOption}{5M4}
\renewcommand*{\ExPart}{AlgebreFinanciere}

\xDeclareExerciseCollection{\ExOption_\ExPart}

\begin{document}

\xcollectexercises{\ExOption_\ExPart}
\begin{exercise}
  Can you print me?
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Yes, you can!
\end{solution}
\xcollectexercisesstop{\ExOption_\ExPart}

\printcollection{5M4_AlgebreFinanciere}

\end{document}
```