# Using \seqsplit with \input

Tags: line-breaking, input, seqsplit

Given a long line stored in an external file, I would like to `\input` it and then use `\seqsplit` to allow it to break as necessary.

a.txt:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

mwe.tex:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\begin{document}
\seqsplit{\input{a.txt}}  % produces `a.txt`

\seqsplit{{\input{a.txt}}}  % produces `a`*101, but not broken

\seqsplit{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}  % produces what I want, but I don't want to have to paste the content in

\end{document}
```

I'm guessing that `\seqsplit` does its processing before the `\input` is run. Is there some way to make this work? I'm willing to use something other than `\seqsplit` of course, I'd just like to be able to break long lines of an external file.

Comment: There are several approaches (expandafter, edef, exp_args, expanded), and this is a common issue, but there's no canonical past question (I can only find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495894/expand-command-in-an-argument-before-the-main-command/495896  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26747/tex-macro-and-command-expansion)

Comment: Interesting! Because it's late and I just want this to work, I'm going to use the command kindly provided in the answer below, but I will come back to these to expand my knowledge of TeX expansions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `catchfile` package to capture the contents of the file. Though apparently `seqsplit` has a bug that causes an error if the sequence ends with a space; and `\CatchFileDef` adds a space to the end of each line by default. I have added `{}` after the sequence to circumvent the bug:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\newcommand\seqsplitinput[1]{%
    \CatchFileDef{\sequence}{#1}{}%
    \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\sequence{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\seqsplitinput{sequence.txt}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can follow egreg's advice and use `\endlinechar=-1` option of `\CatchFileDef`, which will get rid of any endline spaces (and also ignore empty lines in the input file):

```
\newcommand\seqsplitinput[1]{%
    \CatchFileDef{\sequence}{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}%
    \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\sequence}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, and I learned about a new package.

Comment: You can use `\CatchFileDef{\sequence}{#1}{\endlinechar=-1 }` and then `\expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\sequence}`, that's less expensive than your `\edef`.

Comment: Why is `\endlinechar=-1` necessary here?

Comment: @ScottColby, two factors are at work here: (1) `\CatchFileDef` adds one space at the end of each line of the file it reads (regardless of how many spaces were actually there); and (2) `\seqsplit` bugs out with error when the sequence ends with a space. With `\endlinechar=1` `\CatchfileDef` will remove any spaces from the ends of the lines, thus avoiding the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `\input`, even in the primitive form `\@@input`.

Here's an `expl3` command for your job (similar to [July Tikhonov’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622517/4427))

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-seq.tex}
aaaabbbbccccddddddaaaabbbbccccddddddaaaabbbbccccddddddaaaabbbb%
ccccddddddxaaabbbbccccddddddaaaabbbbccccddddddaaaabbbbccccdddd%
ddaaaabbbbccccdddddd
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% make an expl3 version of \seqsplit
\cs_new_eq:NN \colby_seqsplit:n \seqsplit
% define a variant thereof
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \colby_seqsplit:n { V }
% a variable to store the file content
\tl_new:N \l_colby_seqsplit_file_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\seqsplitinput}{m}
 {
  % set the token list variable to the file contents
  \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l_colby_seqsplit_file_tl
  % trim spaces at either end
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_colby_seqsplit_file_tl
  % execute \seqsplit on the file contents
  \colby_seqsplit:V \l_colby_seqsplit_file_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\seqsplitinput{\jobname-seq}

\end{document}
```

[image]